# FluentValidation.MVC vs ServiceStack.FluentValidation.Mvc3

Tags: servicestack, fluentvalidation

http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=mvc

vs

http://www.servicestack.net/

Both have a library which seem to have the same classes.

Both are total different libraries actually.

Can someone tell me why the servicestack has a fluentvalidation assembly just like the codeplex one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Described in [Validation Wiki Page](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Validation) - [ServiceStack](http://www.servicestack.net) includes a port of Fluent Validation library with opinionated integration so it works with ServiceStack's error/validation model, Request method filters and customized error responses.

As with the [ServiceStack's port of the MVC Mini Profiler](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Built-in-profiling) - Deep integration wasn't possible without modifying the source to work with ServiceStack's pipeline.

Comment: I just wanted the fast json encoder/decoder. The Validation library I take then from the origin author. Thanks mythz. erhm... this is you I just see haha ;-)